# gluLookAt not rotating the 'camera'

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I can't seem to figure out how to get a FPS type of movement with my 'camera' using OpenGL ES . I have a cube rendered on the screen, I can move it forward/backward and sideways just fine by changing the first and third argument of the *glTranslatef* function.

The problem starts when I try to rotate the camera using the *gluLookAt* function like this:

```
GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, getX(), 20, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

My cube does rotate, **but it stays in the center and it's z position appears to be slightly changing as well**. I need to make it to rotate not just around it's axis, but away from the camera (by x axis) as well (if the cube was facing me and I rotated 90 degrees, the cube would be on my left).

Any hints on what am I doing wrong? Here's the complete *onDrawFrame*

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glLoadIdentity(); 
    gl.glTranslatef(1, 0.0f, -12.0f + Core.getInstance().getZ()); 
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, Core.getInstance().getX(), 20, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    gl.glVertexPointer( 3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer );
    gl.glDrawElements( GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indexBuffer );

    gl.glDisableClientState( GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
}
```

**EDIT**

I almost managed to get the desired result using the following code:

```
    float x = 4*(float) Math.cos( angle );
    float z = 4*(float) Math.sin( angle );

    GLU.gluLookAt
            (
                    gl,
                    // location
                    x, 0, z,
                    // look at
                    x, 0, z -10,
                    0, 1, 0
            );

    gl.glTranslatef(0, 0.0f, distance );
```

But for some reason the rotations are still a little 'off', it seems like the camera is not totally in the center of the rotation, any suggestions?

Comment: Try drawing a diagram to figure out what your `gluLookAt` call does.

Comment: @immibis don't understand, does the gluLookAt takes care of sin/cos rotation, or do I have to deal with thous calculations?

Comment: What is "sin/cos rotation"? With `gluLookAt`, you say where the camera is, and you say where you want the camera to be looking, and you say which way is up.